# Button release event in android studio 1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

I am creating an android app using android studio version 1.0

By using the following function I'm using click event of a button and its working fine.

```
public void onMnuClick(View v){
    TextView txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R. id.txt) ;
    txt1.setText("menu pressed") ;
}
```

But i need separate events for button press and button release how can that be done?

Comment: @MaxHodges yes..  Its the same question..  But the answer is obsolete and doesnot work in the latest android studio.

Comment: maybe you can edit your question to include the version?